# Error on opening a Web page on remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

When i try to open my Default.aspx page on remote server i get the following error

```
Configuration Error 

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 



Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.




Line 50:             ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
Line 51:         -->
Line 52:        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
Line 53:        <!--
Line 54:             The <customErrors> section enables configuration 


Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\toolbar\web.config    Line: 52
```

how to resolve the above error.what should be the authentication mode. I have placed my website inside C:\inetpub\wwwroot\toolbar and all the files related to my website including web.config are inside the toolbar folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37609.aspx), found by fast Googling..

I assume this will solve your error:

> To resolve it, Right Click on the
>   virtual directory - select properties
>   and then click on "Create" next to the
>   "Application" Label and the textbox.
>   It will automatically create the
>   "application" using the virtual
>   directory's name. Now the application
>   can be accessed.

Comment: What virtual directory?Sorry i did not understand

Comment: Where does the "Default.aspx" is located? How do you manage the website on the remote server?

Comment: its located in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\toolbar

Comment: So "toolbar" is virtual directory. On the remote server (using Remote Desktop) click Start --> Run --> inetmgr and you'll get into IIS management screen. Expand the list on the right. Right click the "toolbar" folder and click the "Create" button next to the "Application" label. Confirm, and you should be able to browse to your Default.aspx page.

Comment: when i right click i get the options as Explore,edit permission,convert to application,add application,add virtual directory,manage folders,refresh,switch to context view. No application label to select Create.why am i not getting that option?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know it's IIS 7 - choose "Convert to application" and type "toolbar" as its Alias. Click OK and it should work.

Comment: I did that as well but a different error comes as Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Install .NET framework 3.5 on the remote server and it should fix that error.

Comment: If my answer did solve your original problem please mark it solved and in case installing the 3.5 framework won't solve the new error post new question with the details. The new error is not related to the previous in any way.